# Memory runs out because of multiple threading in passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

My rails application have AWS server configuration with Apache2 + passenger.
From past 2 days, my server behave differently as I expect.When I restart the server the initially it took very less memory in use and create one thread, then after some minutes the thread were increased and it use most of my server memory and my server is crashed.It gives me log like.

```
[ 2017-06-15 05:01:21.8303 9577/7f54d5583700 age/Cor/Spa/SmartSpawner.h:726 ]: An error occurred while spawning a
process: An error occurred while starting the web application. It
exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.

[ 2017-06-15 05:01:21.8304 9577/7f54d5583700 age/Cor/Spa/SmartSpawner.h:727 ]: The application preloader seems to have crashed, restarting it and trying again... App 700 stderr: Segmentation fault (core dumped) App 700 stderr: : Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)


htop show output as all memory consume by ruby app .
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, suspect that the file is too large so passenger fork fail:

```
App 1242 stderr: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.35/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:67:in `fork'

App 1242 stderr: : Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

Comment: the year is 2022 and I am having this issue. Do you still remember how you managed to fix this? Thanks